# Variable Redux State Structure

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

**Situation:**

I have a tabbed `react-redux` application, and I'm trying to figure out how I should best structure the state (redux store/slices). Each "tab" has a `resourceRef` which looks something like "app://new-tab" or "app://user/1234567890" - and the component that renders when a tab is selected is determined by its `resourceRef` (e.g. an "app://new-tab" resourceRef will render a `<NewTab>` component, an "app://user/1234567890" resourceRef will render a `<UserDisplay>` component, etc.).

Currently I have `tabsSlice` which handles the tabs (adding, removing, updating tab state, etc.). The tabSlice's state looks like the following:

```js
initialState: {
    tabs: [],
    activeTabUid: null
}

// Where tabs look like:
// {
//   title: (String),
//   resourceRef: (String - e.g. "app://new-tab"),
//   uid: (String - unique tab identifier),
//   componentState: (Object - serializable state object)
// }

// And updating a tab's componentState works like so:
reducers: {
    updateTabState: (state, action) => {
        const {updateIndex, tabState} = action.payload;
        state.tabs[updateIndex].componentState = tabState;
    }
}
```

The problem is that I have `componentState` persisted in each tab object of the `tabsSlice` reducer. My current solution is to manage the state at the parent page component level (e.g. `<NewTab>`) - pulling tab state via `useSelector(selectTabState(tabUid))`, and then creating a bunch of state-updating functions to pass down to the child components. This doesn't feel very Redux-y, and I would like to have all of my pages be managed by Redux slices - i.e. have a slice for `<NewTab>`, `<UserDisplay>`, and all of my other possible page components. The problem is, I can't see how to achieve this, since these page states are managed within an array in another slice.

**Question:**

How do I structure this application state such that I can use slices for everything (e.g. a slice inside of a slice)? Is it even possible? If it's not possible, is my current solution a reasonable one?

My understanding of Redux application state structuring is novice at the moment, and so any advice or links to helpful resources would be appreciated.

---

**Clarifying Note:** It's perfectly reasonable to expect multiple tabs of the same page-type in this application. There might be many `UserDisplay` tabs open, for example - each one with its own separate state, displaying a separate user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this architectural challenge by removing page state from the parent tab slice and creating reducer slices for each page-type that I want in my system. Each page slice has a collection of pages of that type, and the actions required for updating any single page.

The following considerations were made:

1. The individual page states (child state) could not be kept within the tabs state (parent state) - it makes some sense to do this, as each page state is always tied to a tab. But there were found to be no good ways to manage complex and variable child component state within a parent slice. If the child pages were not variable, managing it from within the parent would not have been an issue.
2. There may be multiple instance of each page present in the tabs at a given time. This means that a simple slice, meant to handle a single instance of a page would not work - the page slices had to be designed to accommodate any number of pages of their type.

---

An example page slice of this nature might look like:

```js
const initialPageState = {...};

export const slice = createSlice({
  name: <SliceName>,
  initialState: { instances: {} }, // Where a key/value entry looks like {[uid]: state}
  reducers: {
    addPage: (state, action) => {
      const {uid} = action.payload;
      state.instances[uid] = initialPageState;
    },
    removePage: (state, action) => {
      const {uid} = action.payload;
      delete state.instances[uid];
    },

    // Example instance-specific reducer
    setPageValue: (state, action) => {
      const {uid, val} = action.payload;
      state.instances[uid].val = val;
    }
  }
});

export const selectInstance = (uid) => (state) => state.<SliceName>.instances[uid];
```

All references to a tab's `componentState` have been stripped. This did require some additional legwork, creating the connection between `tabSlice` tabs and individual pages within a `pageSlice`. This connection was done through the tab `uid`. And of course there's a bit of code in the background to coordinate between tabs and pages - but hopefully this answer summarizes an effective solution to the type of problem I encountered.

Sometimes if nesting reducers cannot be done with idiomatic and clean Redux code, that reduction should instead be done within separate slices and any necessary state linking can be managed through effective state/action management.